# Oscillating Spring with Pymunk

Tags: python, physics, pyglet, pymunk, pendulum

I am trying to create a pendulum with oscillating string and mass which is expected to oscillate for a period of time and then stop. From what I wrote, the mass could not stop oscillating. Kindly help me out.

```
    import pyglet
    import pymunk
    import chipmunk
    from pymunk import Vec2d
    from pymunk.pyglet_util import DrawOptions

    window = pyglet.window.Window(1300,700,"Oscillation",resizable=False)# 
    W,H
    options=DrawOptions()

    space=pymunk.Space()
    space.gravity= 0,-100




    b0= space.static_body
    p0= 100,200


    body= pymunk.Body(mass=0.5, moment =1)
    body.position = (100,50)
    circle= pymunk.Circle(body, radius=20)

    joint= pymunk.constraint.DampedSpring(b0, body,p0, (0,0), 100, 10, 0)
    space.add(body, circle, joint)

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    space.debug_draw(options)

    def update(dt):
    space.step(dt)

    if __name__=="__main__":
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update,1.0/60)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide damping in the last parameter of the call:

```
joint= pymunk.constraint.DampedSpring(b0, body,p0, (0,0), 100, 10, 0)
```

So it will oscillate forever. Put some amount of damping and it should slow down.

Comment: thank you.  I was able to add some value for the damping and it stopped after some time.  Great grateful.

Comment: @TAYO cool, if the answer was helpful please "accept" it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work